# Array iteration in command to find child items

Tags: windows, powershell

I created a text file containing the child items from the parent folder. I removed the header and called the file. I am able to iterate through the file, but I am unable to forest out the items in the new parent directory.

```
#create txt for array
Get-Item -Path HKLM:\test\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\* | Out-File C:\test\shell.txt
$files = "C:\test\shell.txt"
#removes header
get-content $files | select -Skip 7 | set-content "$files-temp"
move "$files-temp" $files -Force
#iterates array
Get-Content $files | ForEach-Object { Get-Item -Path HKLM:\test\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\$_\* }
```

I need to be able to iterate through the list and obtain the information inside the folders being iterated.

Current output example:

```
Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\TEST\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags


Name                           Property                                                                                                                
----                           --------                                                                                                                
1                                                                                                                                                      
10                                                                                                                                                     
11                                                                                                                                                     
12                                                                                                                                                     
13                                                                                                                                                     
14
```

**_____________________________________________________________________________
Solution**

```
$filedir = "HKLM:\test\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags"
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -Recurse $filedir){
    echo $file >> "C:\test\shell.csv" 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing.  You can list the properties in a key like this.  The path takes wildcards.  `get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`

Comment: Im trying to get the nested items within each folder of the path location. I am iterating through the array to provide the folder location. However, it will only provide me with the folder names as an output and not the items within each folder.

Comment: `Get-childitem -recurse key | get-itemproperty` should dump all the properties except in the top level key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't like how powershell does the registry that much.  Here's a script called "get-itemproperty2.ps1":

```
param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$key)

process { 
  $valuenames = $key.getvaluenames() 

  if ($valuenames) { 
    $valuenames | foreach {
      $value = $_
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Path = $key -replace 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER',
          'HKCU:' -replace 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','HKLM:'
        Name = $Value
        Value = $Key.GetValue($Value)
        Type = $Key.GetValueKind($Value)
      }
    }
  } else {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Path = $key -replace 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER',
        'HKCU:' -replace 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','HKLM:'
        Name = ''
        Value = ''
        Type = ''
    }
  }
}
```

With that in place, you can do:

```
get-item HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\currentversion\run | get-itemproperty2

Path                                                Name           Value                                                  Type
----                                                ----           -----                                                  ----
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\currentversion\run SecurityHealth C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MSASCuiL.exe ExpandString
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\currentversion\run DagentUI       C:\Program Files\Altiris\Dagent\dagentui.exe         String
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\currentversion\run KeyAccess      kass.exe                                             String
```

You can easily export that to csv.  Notice that I used get-item to get the top level key properties.  get-childitem can't even do that.  But you can pipe get-childitem -recurse to get-itemproperty2.